how to get the value on a node that does not have tag - <weci:Leave_of_Absence>
Sample XML:
<weci:Leave_of_Absence weci:isDeleted="1">
    <weci:Leave_Start_Date>2024-04-09-07:00</weci:Leave_Start_Date>
    <weci:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2024-04-08-07:00</weci:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
    <weci:Leave_of_Absence_Type>NoPayLeave</weci:Leave_of_Absence_Type>
</weci:Leave_of_Absence>
<weci:Leave_of_Absence weci:isAdded="1">
    <weci:Leave_Start_Date>2024-04-11-07:00</weci:Leave_Start_Date>
    <weci:Leave_End_Date>2024-04-09-07:00</weci:Leave_End_Date>
    <weci:First_Day_of_Work>2024-04-11-07:00</weci:First_Day_of_Work>
    <weci:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2024-04-08-07:00</weci:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
    <weci:Leave_of_Absence_Type>NoPayLeave</weci:Leave_of_Absence_Type>
</weci:Leave_of_Absence>
<weci:Leave_of_Absence>
    <weci:Leave_Start_Date>2024-04-29-07:00</weci:Leave_Start_Date>
    <weci:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>2024-04-28-07:00</weci:Leave_Last_Day_of_Work>
    <weci:Leave_of_Absence_Type>NoPayLeave</weci:Leave_of_Absence_Type>
</weci:Leave_of_Absence>

Expected Output: 2024-04-29-07:00
If this code is used, it returns all the dates.
<xsl:value-of select="weci:Effective_Change/weci:Leave_of_Absence/weci:Leave_Start_Date"/>
Wrong Output: 2024-04-09-07:00 2024-04-11-07:00 2024-04-29-07:00
Thank you.

I guess you just want to use a predicate on weci:Leave_of_Absence e.g. weci:Leave_of_Absence[not(@*)], but that is meant as an example, I haven't understood from your description what kind of condition exactly you want to check.

Your problem statement is incomplete:  What's different about 2024-04-29-07:00 that makes you want it over any of the weci:Leave_Start_Date values?  Is it something about its string value itself (2024-04-09-07:00, 2024-04-11-07:00,  2024-04-29-07:00)?  Is it something about a sibling element?  Is it something about its position (first, last, nth)?  You need to say.  The connection between "that does not have a tag" and your sample XML is entirely unclear.
